# awk allow associative array contain value as array?

Tags: awk, associative-array

My input data is like

```
key1  value1
key2  value2  value3  value4
key1  value3
```

My expected output will be

```
key1:  value1  value3
key2:  value2  value3 value4
```

I am thinking of using associative map from key to an array. But seems that is not allowed. I am using the implementation below but always get error:

```
function alen(a) {
    k = 0
    for(i in a) k++
    return k
}

BEGIN{}
{
    mylist=mymap[$1];
    mylist[alen( mylist )+1]=$2;   
    <==fatal: attempt to use scalar parameter `a' as an array

    mymap[$1]=mylist;
}
```

The error is "fatal: attempt to use scalar parameter `a' as an array", as when calling alen function on "mylist" as shown above. Any workaround? many thanks

Comment: workaround for what? Line 1 `mylist=mymap[$1]` states that `mylist` is a scalar (initialized to the value stored in `mymap[$1]`) and then line 2 `alen( mylist )` tires to use the scalar variable `mylist` as an array which naturally produces the syntax error message telling you about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) arr[$1] = arr[$1] FS $i} END{for (key in arr) print key ":" arr[key]}' file
key1: value1 value3
key2: value2 value3 value4
```

If not then edit your question to provide a clearer explanation and an example that better demonstrates your needs.

The above will output the key lines in random order due to the `in` operator, easily fixed if that's an issue.